# Which Hindu scriptures use the word Ārya and in what sense?

Tags: vedas, name, etymology, arya

1. What does the word "Ārya" really mean in the context of Hinduism?
2. And which Hindu scriptures use this word and in what sense?

<sub>If you think the question is too broad, limit your answer to The Vedas, Vālmīki Rāmāyaṇa and Mahābhārata.</sub>

Comment: I found the first occurrence at the verse 1.165.5 in the oldest (Rig) Veda.

Comment: I faintly remember that the word Arya was also used to denote Vanara in ValmikiRamayana and it was used to denote the context of 'noble one.'

Comment: @Tezz Think you're referring to [this deleted answer](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/8880/2995).

Comment: @sv. Yes, exactly I was referring to that answer.. I was wondering why I was not able to get it by searching.. I didn't know it was deleted...

Answer (score 10):

The word Arya is used in [Vasistha Dharma Sutras](http://www.astrojyoti.com/vasisthadharmasutras.htm) as follows:

> 8. The country of the **Âryas (Âryâvarta)** lies to the east of the region where (the river Sarasvatî) disappears, to the west of the
>      Black-forest, to the north of the Pâripâtra (mountains), to the south
>      of the Himâlaya. 8
> 9. (According to others it lies to the south of the Himâlaya) and to the north of the Vindhya range (being limited east and west by the two
>      oceans). 9
> 10. Acts productive of spiritual merit, and customs which (are approved of) in that country, must be everywhere acknowledged (as
>       authoritative);
> 11. But not different ones, (i.e. those) of (countries where) laws opposed (to those of Âryâvarta prevail).
> 12. **Some (declare the country of the Âryas to be situated) between the (rivers) Gaṅgâ and Yamunâ.**
>
> **(Vasistha Dharmasutras,Chapter 1)**

Manu Smriti also uses the word Arya or Aryan many a times.This text uses such  words to mean a twice-born who has received his sacraments and who is also performing his duties without failure.

> 2.21. That (country) which (lies) between the Himavat and the Vindhya (mountains) to the east of Prayaga and to the west of Vinasana (the
>   place where the river Sarasvati disappears) is called Madhyadesa (the
>   central region).
>
> [image]
>
> 2.22. **But (the tract) between those two mountains (just mentioned), which (extends) as far as the eastern and the western oceans, the wise
>   call Aryavarta (the country of the Aryans).**
>
> 2.39. After those (periods men of) these three (castes) who have not received the sacrament at the proper time, become Vratyas (outcasts),
>   excluded from the Savitri (initiation) **and despised by the Aryans.**
>
> 2.103. But he who does not (worship) standing in the morning, nor sitting in the evening, **shall be excluded, just like a Sudra, from all
>   the duties and rights of an Aryan**
>
> 2.165. An Aryan must study the whole Veda together with the Rahasyas, performing at the same time various kinds of austerities and the vows
>   prescribed by the rules (of the Veda).
>
> **2.169. According to the injunction of the revealed texts the first birth of an Aryan is from (his natural) mother, the second (happens)
>   on the tying of the girdle of Munga grass, and the third on the
>   initiation to (the performance of) a (Srauta) sacrifice.**

### Arya in the Vedas

I have found more than one references to Arya in the Vedas themselves. Here is one such mantra from Yajur Veda:

> YathA imAm vAcham kalyAnim AvadAni janebhyah (1) BrahmarAjanyAbhyAm
>   sudrAya cha **AryAya** cha (2) SwAya cha aranAya cha (3)
>
> ............
>
> May i speak the sacred word to the masses of the people (janebhya) (1)
>   to the brahmana, kshatriya, to the sudra and the Arya (2) and to our
>   own men and the strangers.
>
> **Shukla Yajur Veda 26.2**

And, here is another mantra from the Atharva Veda:

> Priyam mam krinu deveshu piyam rAjashu mA krinu piyam sarvasya pashyat
>   uta sudra **utArye**.
>
> .............
>
> Make me dear to everyone (to Gods, Kshatriyas etc) and both to sudra
>   and an AryA.
>
> **Atharva Veda 19.62.1**

In these mantras the word Arya simply means a noble one. Also note that, in the first mantra Brahmin, Kshatriya and Arya are all mentioned separately.

So, it implies that it is not necessary for an Arya to belong to a particular caste (varna) like Brahmin or Kshatriya.

Comment: I highly doubt this translation. Do you have Sanskrit Verses?

Comment: @TheDestroyer For VDS i don't have sanskrit verses..

Comment: Manu says आ समुद्रात् तु वै पूर्वादा समुद्राच्च पश्चिमात् ।  तयोरेवान्तरं गिर्योरार्यावर्तं विदुर्बुधाः ॥ २२ ॥ (2.2) but there exists no Eastern and western ocean between Himalayas and Vindhyas. Anyways, i think Arya means just noble people, not particular race. You can get Sanskrit verses for Manusmriti [here](http://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/manusmriti-with-the-commentary-of-medhatithi/d/doc145592.html).

Comment: @TheDestroyer Yes Arya means one who's worthy of initiation and also one who after initiation  performs his duties as prescribed in Shastras without fail..Noble one is also right but that definition/translation is somewhat vague IMO..

Comment: So, is śiṣṭa a proper term for Ārya?

Comment: Yes Sista is a proper description @Bingming